# Identical Resources Loaded Multiple Times by Facebook Social Plugins

Tags: facebook, performance

I've run a [Pingdom.com test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/nALHTwFMr/http://jujjem.com/dave-matthews/) on my page and found out that identical JS files from Facebook are being loaded twice. Once from http://s-static.ak.facebook.com/ and another time from http://static.ak.fbcdn.net. Pingdom is reporting that the page size is 753.7kB. That's a lot, and if you exclude Facebook resources, the page size goes down more than 60%—what a waste! Is there any way to mitigate this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use a [channel file](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

> The channelUrl parameter is optional, but recommended. Providing a
>   channel file can help address three specific known issues. First,
>   pages that include code to communicate across frames may cause Social
>   Plugins to show up as blank without a channelUrl. Second, if no
>   channelUrl is provided and a page includes auto-playing audio or
>   video, the user may hear two streams of audio because the page has
>   been loaded a second time in the background for cross domain
>   communication. Third, a channel file will prevent inclusion of extra
>   hits in your server-side logs. If you do not specify a channelUrl, you
>   can remove page views containing fb_xd_bust or fb_xd_fragment
>   parameters from your logs to ensure proper counts.
>
> The channelUrl must be a fully qualified URL matching the page on
>   which you include the SDK. In other words, the channel file domain
>   must include www if your site is served using www, and if you modify
>   document.domain on your page you must make the same document.domain
>   change in the channel.html file as well. The protocols must also
>   match. If your page is served over https, your channelUrl must also be
>   https. Remember to use the matching protocol for the script src as
>   well. The sample code above uses protocol-relative URLs which should
>   handle most https cases properly.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what to do with this information or how it'll help. I'm a lousy web developer, I guess...

Comment: can you create a channel file and point to it from the JS-SDK?

Comment: I created a channel.php file, placed it at the root of my site, and I pointed to it from the JS-SDK. Then I checked my page size again and it didn't change at all.

Comment: are you sure about the reading? the Network tab in Google Chrome is showing normal results?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Web Inspector Network tab (with caching disabled option) is what I used to check the results before and after.

Comment: Well I tried disabling cache, and I couldn't see any duplicates in the resources loaded. Facebook resources are about 277.75KB which is fine considering that most likely the user will land on your page with these files already downloaded (from previous websites...etc). I really can't see an issue here.

Comment: I used Web Inspector again, but this time from Incognito. It seems that when you're not logged in to Facebook, fewer resources get requested. The total size of the page is around 300KB in that cause, which is fine. So, I guess you're right, I'm making an issue out of nothing. I'll just leave things as is. Thanks for your help!